# WP7 - how to let user set app theme

Tags: windows-phone-7

My app has 10 pages and all of them have black background. I want to let user change background color of all pages using radioButton in my app. How can I do this in easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Go through these blogs

[1. Theme Forcing for Windows Phone 7](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/) or,

[2. Windows Phone Mango Custom application Theme](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-mango-custom-application-theme-step-by-step)

these might prove helpful to you. You can study these and modify to put them in your settings page.

Thank You :)

Comment: Maybe I used wrong words. I want to allow user change this color in settings page in my app

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have 10 pages and on each page you want to change the background colour of those pages through the settings menu. What you can do is use the Windows Phone `IsolatedStorageSettings`.

Firstly you want to initialize the IsolatedStorageSettings. You can do that like this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings MyAppSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

Then you will have to set a default value for it so it doesn't throw an exception. You can do this:

```
MyAppSettings.Add("PageBackgroundColor", "#000000"); // you can set whatever the default colour you want here. i.e. Black
```

the best place i think would be is to add this code in:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{

if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("PageBackgroundColor"))
        {
            // Don't do anything because you've already set the default background colour for the pages
        }
        else
        {
             // add the default color 
        }
}
```

Now in your MainPage you can reinitialize the `IsolatedStorageSettings`. Once you've done that you will want to get the value of the setting and depending on the value you will want to change the background color. To read the value:

```
string Sortval = (string)MyAppSettings["PageBackgroundColor"];
```

You can add this in the:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Or

```
public MainPage
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

**`Remember that public MainPage will only run once and the OnNavigatedTo runs every time the page is loaded so if you want to update the background color right after adding the setting, OnNavigatedTo is the way to go but if you want to apply the changes after a restart, public Mainpage is it.`**

Now to read the value and change it you want to do something like:

```
string val = (string)MyAppSettings["PageBackgroundColor"];
if (val == "#000000")
{
   //change to black
}
else if (val == "your hex color")
{
   //change to whatever color
}
else if (val == "another hex color")
{
   //...
}
```

Now to save the value you want to reinitialize the `IsolatedStorageSettings` in your settings page and to save the values it would be something like this:

```
 MyAppSettings.Remove("PageBackgroundColor");
 MyAppSettings.Add("PageBackgroundColor", "your hex color");
 MyAppSettings.Save();
```

This is untested however It should give you the very basic idea on how to do it in terms of saving and loading setting and then applying it